# How to have a core class call a Client Class?

Tags: c#, .net, compact-framework, windows-mobile-6.5

I am trying to build a core application that uses plugins so that the core never changes and each time we get a new client we write a module for them. We implement a interface called IClientPlugin with the new customer class.

This is using Compact Framework 3.5 and windows mobile 6.5.3.

So here is what I need to acheive:

this is a warehouse management system. The first task is to receive in the product from a truck scanning barcodes off packages with the handheld device.

The core module for this is started when the person clicks the receiving menu item.

the core method is - `callClientMethod()`

I know the client name and it is stored in a global variable at login and the class will be `{clientname}.cs`
and contain a method called `processReceiving()`.

I know how to instantiate this object.

The question is: is there a way I can dynamically create a instance of the client class without hardcoding case statements?

For example suppose I have 2 clients Acme and Widgets. They each get a client class, namely `Acme.cs` and `Widgets.cs`

If I login as Acme or Widgets I want the code to dynamically create a instance of the Client class that I logged in as so that the core code does not have to change as I add more clients as long as I add a module for them.

psuedo example:

```
var myClient = New (Clientname)();
```

Is this possible or is there a better design approach or is the switch/case statement a neccessary evil?

Comment: Angle brackets get eaten by the system so I changed it to `{clientname}.cs`. Not being a c# programmer I have no idea if that is acceptable for indicating boilerplate.

Comment: I think people will still get the point thanks verbela.

Comment: Do client classes reside in the same assembly?

Comment: the assembly is located not in
the GAC but in the application directory and are in 2 diffrent parts of the project but reside in the same project

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use reflection to create objects dynamically.
There are many ways to load a type or assembly. Lets start with a simple one:

```
Type clientType = Type.GetType("AssemblyName, TypeName");
IClientPlugin clientPlugin = 
                   (IClientPlugin)Activator.CreateInstance(clientType);
```

If your client is named *myClient1* and you have the convention, that your assemblies are named for example like *Clients.ClientName.dll* then you can write a function:

```
IClientPlugin CreatePluginInstance(string clientName) {
    string typeName = string.Format("Clients.{0}, {0}", clientName);
    Type clientType = Type.GetType(typeName);
    IClientPlugin clientPluginInstance = 
                      (IClientPlugin)Activator.CreateInstance(clientType);    
    return clientPluginInstance;
}
```

**EDIT**

If your plugin classes are located in the same assembly as your main project, you can simplify the call of Type.GetType to just specify the classname:

```
Type.GetType(clientName);
```

Comment: Thank you for that but is there a way to refrence them in the project outside of dll's. I was trying to avoid building full blown factories as there are some young developers that will have to maintain this that do not yet have a full grasp of advanced .net principles.

Comment: I don't know what you mean with *project outside of dll's*. Can you elaborate on that?

Comment: yes the class I am referencing is not in a dll it is in a sub directory of the project i am working in

Comment: how can I solve this problem if the assembly is located not in
the GAC but in the application directory?
thats what I mean sorry been up all night my programmer speak is not what it should be

Comment: No problem :) To undderstand you correctly: Your client classes are not in the applications dll but in separate dlls located in your app directory? This is no problem. The default assembly/type loader will look in your local application directory for assemblies. You don't have to reference them, they just have to be located side by side to your applications exe.

Comment: they are not in dll's at all  this is all in the same project precompile they are in diffrent directories in the project they are just code files atm

Comment: So they are compiled into your application assembly (exe)? Even simpler. Then you have to tell `Type.GetType()` with just the name of the class: `Type.GetType("MyClientClass")`

Comment: amazing you are awesome thanks a bunch load I was overcomplicating it thats why it wasn't working .

Answer (score 0):

```
var myClient = Activator.CreateComInstanceFrom("Acme.dll","Acme");
```

Where you can parametrize the Assembly name and the type name.

Comment: Thank you for that but is there a way to refrence them in the project outside of dll's. I was trying to avoid building full blown factories as there are some young developers that will have to maintain this that do not yet have a full grasp of advanced .net principles